# Grouping vectors into groups of 3 by attribute

Tags: matrix, computational-geometry, vector, application

Three groups are given, each with eight $3 \times3$-vectors:

```
V1={{-0.0953681318008175,0.858850259468781,0.46532773783586},
    {-0.743367248943597,0.315573550722436,-0.557734004373653},
    {0.683550749866093,-0.246647785705382,0.659675673733952},
    {-0.181058614839515,-0.767007049361869,-0.584950182984675},
    {0.118761748181243,0.743380411572561,0.62970625152634},
    {-0.72191242346933,0.520402704143404,-0.413850493189363},
    {0.684870513276088,-0.444565219875274,0.54457588789296},
    {0.00541628034354009,-0.874348540602108,-0.445795968809064}}

V2={{0.288328864090772,0.663613522812372,-0.690270583470916},
    {-0.066165547585985,0.71448637679447,0.696506466316257},
    {0.0659856355945583,-0.714480201575689,-0.696529868264201},
    {-0.290257865507787,-0.355082937133591,0.888626130158261},
    {0.293720151348812,0.45310807315223,-0.841671828368103},
    {0.0218190503132586,0.884590829792312,0.465846447687839},
    {-0.0107163145532371,-0.867045341360451,-0.498103861217854},
    {-0.293858044300728,-0.55537492448856,0.777943483153936}}

V3={{-0.983704829430046,0.127754733568269,-0.126193025298098},
    {0.569942911640406,0.507765297260453,-0.64595713742929},
    {-0.600866408147646,-0.493858673852356,0.628477774346492},
    {0.913781057203716,-0.270305866504114,0.303084247456218},
    {-0.90298718075104,0.284301799787109,-0.322036925000972},
    {0.766156223036288,0.39184225900521,-0.509298958360849},
    {-0.772797513782289,-0.387356431991189,0.502653101367087},
    {0.9845954062143,-0.125219791950337,0.121708803266623}}
```

**Task:**

it is necessary to take a vector from each group and compose a basis in such a way that the angles between the corresponding pairs of vectors (i.e. $acos(cos(V1_{:,i}V2_{:,i})),acos(cos(V2_{:,i}V3_{:,i})),acos(cos(V3_{:,i}V1_{:,i}))$) are the same or differ insignificantly, i.e. the result should be 8 bases that meet these requirements.

How to do it?

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: @MariusLadegårdMeyer only manually, by brute force. Otherwise I don't know how

Comment: @MariusLadegårdMeyer Is there some kind of mathematical apparatus for this, or do you have to program an iterative loop?

Comment: Unless I made a mistake just now, I don't think this can be done (unless you loosen the requirement for the angles). Computing all possible angles between vectors from two different sets, I find no duplicate angles, let alone triples. I have to round the angles to `0.003` to get enough repeats in the angles for this to be possible at all.

Comment: @LukasLang Yes, let's make the requirements less stringent, I don't mind. How did you do it?